# Conversion of module.exports from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have Node-express code where modules are exported by using module.exports. For example, to export a function, it is written module.exports = functionName. Now the code will be converted to typescript. How to replace module.exports in typescript?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `export` followed by the typical declaration, no matter whether it is a `const`, `function`, `interface`, `enum`, you name it.

```
export const myTestConst = () => console.log('hello world');
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 3):

Adding up to duschsocke answer. You can also create a class with public methods and importing that class where you need those methods.

**utils.ts**

```
class Utils {

  public static publicFunction() {
    console.log('calling me');
  }
}
```

**On other ts file:**

```
import * as utils from 'utils';

// Call the function
utils.publicFunction(); // Prints 'calling me' on console.
```

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, use [`export = functionName`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).